# Convert a number to a list of his digits in f#

Tags: list, f#

For example:

Number is 238

Result is [2;3;8]

I'm trying to do it in f# but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: An exercise? What have you tried, can you show us your code that isn't working? Know that you'll need `x % 10` in a recursive loop.

Comment: Or you can do `(string x).ToCharArray() |> Array.map Int32.Parse |> Array.toList` if you'd want to be creative ;)

Comment: @Abel Thanks for the suggestion, it works now!

Comment: `let rec number_to_list n = if n=0 then [] else let x = n/10 let y = n%10 number_to_list x @ [y]`

Comment: perfect, well done! You can opt to answer your own question then :)

Comment: Btw, using `@` is relatively slow, O(n), using `::` is O(1). If possible, try to code reversion with lists using `::`. In this case, it would be something like `let rec g k x = if x = 0 then k else f (x % 10::k) (x / 10)`. Call it with `g List.empty 12345`, or wrap the `rec` function in an inner function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I got with the help of Abel:

`let rec number_to_list n = if n=0 then [] else let x = n/10 let y = n%10 number_to_list x @ [y]`